# Sharepoint 2013 OOTB Survey Redirect

Tags: 2013

I have a question regarding Out of the box survey apps on SharePoint 2013.

I have been tasked with creating a new "Thank You" page for when a response to a survey is completed. Once the "Finish" button is clicked in the OOTB SharePoint 2013 Survey app the user will then be redirected to a thank you page.

I used to be able to do this in 2007 when I used a custom list for a survey by changing the "Source" of the URL.

I am just wondering, is it possible to redirect a user to a thank you page in SharePoints OOTB Survey app? If so, how would you suggest going about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/sharepoint-survey-redirect-to-thank-you-page-on-finish.html

Procedure:

You can use the SharePoint Designer to achieve it.

- Create a new page named as “Thankyou.aspx” page under the Site Pages.
- Open the site in SharePoint Designer 2013, click Lists and Libraries, go to "Forms" section. Create a New Form by clicking on "New Item Form"
- Give it a Name,  choose form type as "New Item Form" and enable "Set as default form for the selected type" and click on "Ok" to create the new form.
- Edit the New form we've just created. Open the "New.aspx" page with Advanced Mode in SharePoint Designer.
- Search for the savebutton1,savebutton2, delete all two “Finish” buttons.
- Insert SharePoint Form Action button from "Insert Menu >> SharePoint >> Form Action Button"
- Select the Form Actions "Commit" and "Navigate to Page" .
- Select the “Navigate to page” action, click “settings” to set the target page ,and click "OK".
- Rename the Form Action as Finish.
- Save and close the page.

You can also refer to the following article, although it is for SharePoint 2010, it also fits for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Hi sathish, do you happen to know if this is the only way to accomplish this goal? Is it possible in any other way as I currently do not have SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Using Designer is the easiest way to achieve from requirement [reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/77009cb5-4951-427d-8c23-5a75aff74290/survey-redirect-to-thank-you-page-after-finishing-the-survey?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)